# I want to pass a string array to main but keep spaces in groovy

Tags: groovy, command-line-arguments

My groovy clas has this method

```
void runCmd(String[] args) {        
    println runFunction(args)
}
```

When I pass command line argument enable-function 100, "o= my organization"
args.size(), ideally it should return 2 , but it return value 3 as it is treating "o= my organization" as 2 argument instead of one.

Comment: Have you tried quoting your CLI arguments?

Comment: Yes, I am doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...as it is treating "o= my organization" as 2 argument instead of one

"o= my organization" can be treated as 1 argument.

```
$ cat Demo.groovy 
class Demo {
  static void main(args) {
      println "Number Of Arguments: ${args.length}"
      args.each {
          println "\t $it"
      }
  }
}

$ groovy Demo one
Number Of Arguments: 1
  one
 $ 
 $ groovy Demo one two
Number Of Arguments: 2
  one
  two
 $ 
 $ groovy Demo 100 "o= my organization" 
Number Of Arguments: 2
     100
     o= my organization
```